# Change password failed for a tester user. I cannot find the error

Tags: python, django

[image: Error]

User Tester cannot change their password. I used ChatGPT for help, but it fails. What ought I to change/correct? User logs into the My_account website and tries to change the password, but nothing happens.

> With this change, the user is always returned to the "my_account" page after saving the password, regardless of whether the password was changed or not. If the password has been changed, the success message is displayed, otherwise the error message. The new password is only saved if it has been successfully changed

-- this doesn't happen

`views.py`

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views import View
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordChangeForm
from .models import Note

class MyAccountView(View):
    template_name = "my_account.html"

    def get(self, request):
        password_form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user)
        notes = Note.objects.filter(user=request.user)

        context = {"password_form": password_form, "notes": notes}

        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def post(self, request):
        password_form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user, request.POST)

        if 'change_password' in request.POST:
            if password_form.is_valid():
                user = password_form.save()
                update_session_auth_hash(request, user)
                messages.success(request, "Successfully changed.")
                return redirect("my_account")
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Error changing the password. Please check your entries.")
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("my_account"))

         # If the password has not been changed or the password form is invalid,
        # redirect the user back to the MyAccount page with the error messages.
        notes = Note.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        context = {"password_form": password_form, "notes": notes}
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

`my_account.html`

```
{% extends 'dependencies.html' %} {% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <h1>Mein Konto</h1>

    <!--Showing sucess reports-->
    {% if messages %}
    <div class="alert alert-success"
        <ul>
            {% for message in messages %}
            <li>{{ message }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
        <h2>Passwort ändern</h2>
        <form method="post" id="password-form">
            {% csrf_token %} {{ password_form.non_field_errors }}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="{{ password_form.old_password.id_for_label }}"
                    >Altes Passwort:</label
                >
                {{ password_form.old_password }} {{
                password_form.old_password.errors }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="{{ password_form.new_password1.id_for_label }}"
                    >Neues Passwort:</label
                >
                {{ password_form.new_password1 }} {{
                password_form.new_password1.errors }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="{{ password_form.new_password2.id_for_label }}"
                    >Passwort bestätigen:</label
                >
                {{ password_form.new_password2 }} {{
                password_form.new_password2.errors }}
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                Passwort ändern
            </button>
        </form>

        <h2>Notiz hinzufügen</h2>
        <form method="post" id="note-form">
            {% csrf_token %} {{ note_form.non_field_errors }}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="{{ note_form.content.id_for_label }}">Notiz:</label>
                {{ note_form.content }} {{ note_form.content.errors }}
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                Notiz hinzufügen
            </button>
        </form>

        <h2>Meine Notizen</h2>
        <ul>
            {% for note in notes %}
            <li>{{ note.content }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: "With this change ..." What is that quote from?

Comment: How does `'change_password'` get into the POST data. Wouldn't you have to add that as a name to the submit button/input?

Comment: I am not sure how to correct it, so that it changes the password. Any ideas?